# Timer speed Problem WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am using timer to scroll the list. Every millisecond interval i am initiating the Tick event. Event though the animation looks very slow.

```
 repeatTimer_Tick(this, new EventArgs());
        repeatLeftTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
        repeatLeftTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(repeatTimer_Tick);
```

Comment: Is it WPF or ASP.NET ? These technologies don't work together, it doesn't make sense to include both tags...

Answer (score 2):

The timers in windows have a resolution of several milliseconds, IIRC, something between 10 and 50 ms. You can't get the normal timer to tick every millisecond.

Comment: is there any solution for this?

Comment: I think the timer resolution is at best 13ms. Which is ~75fps. Do you really need more than 75fps in your animation? If you must animate using a timer then calculate a delta value between the previous frame and animate using the delta.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use a `BackgroundWorker`, scroll your listbox in the `ProgressChanged` event handler and call `yourWorker.ReprotProgress` in a loop with `Sleep(1000)` in between...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth good idea ... I've found calling Sleep(1) is good - it basically frees up the minimum amount of time to other threads/processes and prevents the background worker's loop from taking up 100% of CPU. Every iteration of the loop you just get the current time but only do something whenever (current time - last time) >= timer_period.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use an animation for what you're doing.

The .NET timer classes generally have a minimum interval of 15.6 ms.  If you need a faster increment (down to 1ms) Windows provides a multimedia timer in the unmanaged API.  You could import this timer and use it -- I've done it and it works.

I based my code off of this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/lescsmultimediatimer.aspx

Should be most of what you need; I added some code to look at the high resolution timer and observe the time between ticks -- I was able to get it to 1ms, += 0.10 ms

Answer (score 0):

You have two good and (relatively) easy options:

1. Use an animation - WPF has a very versatile animation system that is likely to be able to do what you need.
2. Use the CompositionTarget.Rendering Event, those are called as fast as possible (each frame) and you are responsible in each call to set the current status based on the current time (that is how the built in animations work)

Comment: i am having a list box with more that 1000 records. i have ordered the records with 5 rows and in each column. I want to move each column horizontally

Comment: @Geetha - ok, you still have those two options, you can use a DoubleAnimation to scroll the columns or you can use CompositionTarget.Rendering and a little bit of math - this is the system created to support smooth animations in WPF

Answer (score 0):

If you need a high resolution then I would suggest looking into the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class. Use the Frequency field and the ElapsedTicks property to get the resolution you are looking for. Note though that the resolution of the stopwatch will change depending on the hardware. Read the link to the msdn documentation for more information.