# How can I add millisecond delay to my TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, image

I am using the code below as it only works with `int` value greater than one.

Does any one have idea of can I change it with `millisecond` value or even no delay at all? or any other alternative method?

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
timer.Tick += delegate
{
    timer.Stop();
    // my image code generator
    timer.Start();
};
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Even if you fix your issue of setting the time, I don't know of any timer that has a resolution below 15 milliseconds. you may need to re-think your architecture.

Comment: I think you're looking for `while (true) {...}` lol

Comment: @ProgrammerDan this is a C# question, not a java question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry, missed that! Thanks.

Comment: Ref. [this answer which mentions a "fast resolution" Windows Multimedia Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6749354/2864740). A while (true) busy-loop will only *trash* a CPU core and using `Thread.Sleep` will consume ~15ms of wall-clock before the thread context is active again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a constructor for that pupose:

```
TimeSpan(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32);
```

So:

```
new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: does this run every 1 millisecond? and where should i put the contractor?

Comment: @BlueSky It will run "as fast as the timers minimum resolution", which depends on implementation and environment. A DispatchTimer uses the Dispatch queue, so I'd expect the minimum resolution to be *at least* 15ms. [MSDN only says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx): "Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs."